# Highlighting selected rows in a Dash datatable

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I’m looking to highlight only selected rows in a Dash datatable, but I can only get it to highlight all cells in the table or none at all. The app.callback I am attempting to use is modified from code to highlight selected columns ([found here](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/interactivity)):

```
@app.callback(Output('datatable-interactivity', 'style_data_conditional'),
             [Input('datatable-interactivity', 'selected_rows')])
def update_styles(selected_rows):
    return [{'if': {'derived_virtual_selected_row_ids': i}, 'background_color': '#D2F3FF'} for i in selected_rows]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue when I initially looked at plotly's documentation.  You must have in your data for the table an "id" key/value that you can use to uniquely identify that row of data.  You also need to use the "filter_query" in your if statement.  See the example below.

```
@app.callback(
    Output("table", "style_data_conditional"),
    Input("table", "derived_virtual_selected_row_ids"),
)
def style_selected_rows(sel_rows):
    if sel_rows is None:                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        return dash.no_update
    val = [
        {"if": {"filter_query": "{{id}} ={}".format(i)}, "backgroundColor": "#404040",}
        for i in sel_rows
    ]   
    return val
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the your condition should be checking the `row_index` and not `derived_virtual_selected_row_ids`.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue and I was looking to be able to click anywhere in the table and have it select the row and I got that to work, but the result is not pretty...

The first time you select a cell it still shows the red background, even though I had set the background to the blue I wanted in the setup of the table. Then there is a noticeble delay when I use the selected cell as the trigger to select the row it is in...I also had to zero out the SELECTED_CELLS attribute, since even though I set the active_cell, it still showed the selected cell in red, even after I had set the background...

[image: test Dash Datatable]

But here's the code as a full example and if someone knows how to clean this up I am listening...:

```py
from dash import Dash, Input, Output, State, dcc, html, no_update, dash_table
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP]
app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

df = pd.read_csv('https://git.io/Juf1t')
df['id'] = df.State

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Label('Click a cell in the table:'),
    dash_table.DataTable(
        df.to_dict('records'),
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns[:-2]],
        row_selectable='single',
        cell_selectable=True,
        style_data_conditional=[
            {
                "if": {
                    "state": "active"  # 'active' | 'selected'
                },
                "backgroundColor": "rgba(0, 116, 217, 0.3)",
                "border": "1px solid rgb(0, 116, 217)",
            },
            {
                "if": {
                    "state": "selected"  # 'active' | 'selected'
                },
                "backgroundColor": "rgba(0, 116, 217, 0.3)",
                "border": "1px solid rgb(0, 116, 217)",
            }

        ],
        id='tbl'),
    dbc.Alert(id='tbl_out'),
    dbc.Alert(id='tbl_out2'),
])


@app.callback(
    (
        Output('tbl_out', 'children'),
        Output('tbl','selected_rows'),
    ), Input('tbl', 'active_cell'),
    prevent_initial_call=True)
def update_graphs(active_cell):
    return (
        str(active_cell),
        [active_cell['row']],
    ) if active_cell else (str(active_cell),no_update)


@app.callback(
    (
        Output('tbl_out2', 'children'),
        Output('tbl','style_data_conditional'),
        Output('tbl','active_cell'),
        Output('tbl','selected_cells')
    ),
    Input('tbl', 'derived_viewport_selected_row_ids'),
    State('tbl', 'derived_viewport_selected_rows'),
    State('tbl', 'active_cell'),
    State('tbl', 'selected_cells'),
    prevent_initial_call=True)
def update_graphs2(selected_row_ids,selected_rows, active_cell, selected_cells):
    if selected_row_ids:
        if active_cell:
            active_cell['row'] = selected_rows[0]
        else:
            active_cell = no_update
        return (
            str(f'{selected_row_ids} {selected_rows} {active_cell} {selected_cells}'),
            [
                {
                    "if": {
                        "filter_query": "{{id}} = '{}'".format(i)
                    },
                    "backgroundColor": "rgba(0, 116, 217, 0.3)",
                    "border": "1px solid rgb(0, 116, 217)",
                } for i in selected_row_ids
            ] + [
                {
                    "if": {
                        "state": "active"  # 'active' | 'selected'
                    },
                    "backgroundColor": "rgba(0, 116, 217, 0.3)",
                    "border": "1px solid rgb(0, 116, 217)",
                }
            ],
            active_cell,
            []
        )
    else:
        return ("Click the table", [], no_update, [])
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```